# Python implementation of sha512_crypt.c

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, cryptography, sha

I'm looking for a 100% pure Python implementation of sha512_crypt.c as taken from http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt.

I'm learning Python. I want to understand the code (and compare it to the C code, etc.). I don't know enough Python to write it myself -- even if I did, I wouldn't trust myself to get it right. I don't have that expertise. So please don't answer this question by telling me to go write the code myself. That's not my question. I am looking for an *existing* 100% Python implementation that gives the same output as [the original sha512_crypt.c written by Ulrich Drepper](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt).

Just to be sure my question is clear, answers I'm looking for are probably either:

1. "I know for sure that a 100% Python implementation of that C code doesn't exist."
2. "Here is the link to the Python code that you can download."

(Even though I'm not asking for help writing specific code, I was told to post here as a result of a meta discussion. This question is, after all, about studying Python code.)

BTW, I know there is a Java implementation here: ftp://ftp.arlut.utexas.edu/java_hashes/

I'm looking for the Python equivalent.

Thank you.

UPDATE: [james-mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364980/james-mills) answered the question for me. But today I just learned about Nullege: A Search Engine for Python source code
http://www.nullege.com/
That could come in handy in the future.

I also learned that startpage.com will accept "filetype:py" as a search term and it returns some good results. Unfortunately, I tried the same with duckduckgo and it didn't return any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.html) it seems to have a pure Python implemtnation of `SHA512 crypt` that it falls back to:

> This class will use the first available of two possible backends:
>   stdlib crypt(), if the host OS supports SHA512-Crypt (most Linux systems).
>   a pure python implementation of SHA512-Crypt built into passlib.
>   You can see which backend is in use by calling the get_backend() method.

Found the source code: https://code.google.com/p/passlib/source/browse/passlib/handlers/sha2_crypt.py

Comment: I thought Passlib might have the pure Python implementation, but when I went looking for the Python source I could not find it. If you manage to find a link to the source I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I'm trawling through the codebase myself. The statement from their documetnation may in fact be wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit subjective because you have so many choices, but try this: [http://google.com/search?q="sha512_crypt"+filetype:py](http://google.com/search?q=%22sha512_crypt%22%20filetype:py). Notice the quotes around the filename to ensure you get an exact match (Google will treat the underscore as a space otherwise).

I'm not familiar with Drepper's work or Python, so I could not say if any are any exact matches.

[image: Google search for sha512_crypt]

Comment: None of those results answer this question. The question was very specific. The SHA512 algorithm in Python is not an answer to this question. I'm not sure how to make the question any more clear. However, someone already answered it correctly.

Comment: In that case, you might try https://www.google.com/search?q="sha512_crypt"+filetype:py. Notice the quotes around the filename to ensure you get an exact match (Google will treat the underscore as a space). I'm not familiar with Drepper's work or Python, so I could not say if any are any exact matches.

Comment: MountainX - this might help too, if interested in reading about Python and crypto: [Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python: A beginner's guide to cryptography and computer programming with Python](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1482614375).

Comment: Thanks for the additional recommendations. Using "sha512_crypt" with filetype:py does turn up the source code that James Mills found in his answer. And that code is a Python implementation of Drepper's C code, which is what I was looking for. :-)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Done. Quotes and filetype should be helpful to you in the future for things like this.